# How to restrict displaying minus values in the text field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[**Fiddle**.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5664/)

I have a text field, I want to restrict showing negative values to this text field, if I got negative value then I dont want to display that value in the text box.But my ng-model should contain that negative value.

```
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.number = -10;
  $scope.number1 = -20;
  $scope.number2 = -30;
}
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <input ng-model="number"></input>
  <input ng-model="number1"></input>
  <input ng-model="number2"></input>
  <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" onkeypress="OnlyNumber(this);"></input>
</body>
<script>
function OnlyNumber(i)
{
    if(i.value.length>0)
    {
    i.value = i.value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Use this javascript code.
I have used `onkeypress` javascript attribute
You can use `ng-keyup` angularjs directive

[check here](https://plnkr.co/edit/c5jH5yZv8GUREpzBU7Xz?p=preview)

Comment: it is allowing negative values to display, I have given`ng-model = -0` and it is displaying

Comment: you can  use a custome directive which will not display negative sign in text field. check this `url https://codepen.io/apuchkov/pen/ILjFr`

Comment: may I know one example for custome directive

Comment: check this link also https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/angularjs-directive-to-allow-number-only-in-textbox/

Answer (score 0):

No need to use javascript at all. 
Convert

```
<input ng-model="number"></input>
```

to

```
<input type="number" min="0" ng-model="number"></input>
```

for every `input` tag you need.

P.S: This will not perform *not-showing* when onLoad and copy/paste is the action but issue a warning that the value is not eligible for the input.

Comment: This will not satisfy OPs requirement as the input field is going to show blank for negative values.

Comment: @CharlieH Is that not THE requirement? _if I got negative value then I dont want to display that value in the text box._

Comment: @mplugjan, well not indeed. Going to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cleanInput(selector){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for(element in elements){
       if(parseInt(element.value) < 0 ) {element.value = '';}
    }        
}
```

Provided that this is your HTML:

```
<div id="clean-div" ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
<input ng-model="number"></input>
<input ng-model="number1"></input>
<input ng-model="number2"></input>
<input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
```

Then,

```
cleanInput('#clean-div input');
```

EDIT: Solution by using HTML, is only valid for newer browsers. If you don't care, go ahead with input type=number solution. Else JavaScript is needed.

Comment: Where are you binding the code to the input? In CSS or something? He HAS JavaScript - it is AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

```
//try using conditional expression like this.
function LoginController($scope) {
    let num=-10
    $scope.number = num<0?'':num;
}
```

Comment: Will this stop the user from entering a new negative number?

Comment: this won't stop user from entering -ve number but it will make the model empty whenever the -ve value is entered. if your requirement is to stop user  from entering negative number then you should do <input type='number' min='0'> in your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="number" id="numval" min="0" />
 </form>

// Select your input element.
var number = document.getElementById('numval');

// Listener for input element.
 number.onkeydown = function(e) {
if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
  || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
  || e.keyCode == 8)) {
    return false;
}
}
```

95, < 106 corresponds to Numpad 0 through 9;
47, < 58 corresponds to 0 through 9 on the Number Row; and 8 is Backspace.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML :

<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <input ng-model="number" ng-change="onNumberChange('number')">
</input>
    <input ng-model="number1" ng-change="onNumberChange('number1')">
</input>
    <input ng-model="number2" ng-change="onNumberChange('number2')">
</input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
</div>

Controller :

function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.number = -10;
    $scope.number1 = -20;
    $scope.number2 = -30;

$scope.onNumberChange = function(valueName){
    var number  = parseInt($scope[valueName]);
  if(number < 0){
    $scope[valueName] = 0
  }
}
```

}